# How to separate mixed Home directory files and User created files - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls, ubuntu-20.04, home-directory

I have download android source code in `/home/username/` directory, without creating separate folder(`/home/username/folder`).
Now my home directory files and downloaded files are mixed. How to find and seperate my downloaded files in `/home/username/`.

when i `ls -lta` it is listing all latest modified files in top. But among those files `.bashrc`, `.bash_history`, `.bash_logout` files also coming which is system  created files.

Now nearly 60 files are there in my `home/username/` directory. How to find and separate these?

```
pc:~$ ls -lta
total 324
drwx------  27 username  username   4096 Dec  1 16:33  .config
drwxrwxr-x  32 username  username   4096 Dec  1 16:21  prebuilts
drwxrwxr-x  45 username  username   4096 Dec  1 16:18  system
drwxrwxr-x  21 username  username   4096 Dec  1 16:16  sdk
drwxr-xr-x  55 username  username   4096 Dec  1 16:15  .
drwxrwxr-x  24 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:44  tools
drwxrwxr-x  12 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:31  test
drwxrwxr-x   4 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:30  toolchain
drwxrwxr-x   9 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:18  packages
drwxrwxr-x  10 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:07  platform_testing
drwxrwxr-x   6 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:07  pdk
drwxrwxr-x   5 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:07  kernel
drwxrwxr-x  16 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:06  frameworks
drwxrwxr-x  10 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:04  libnativehelper
drwxrwxr-x  20 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:04  libcore
drwxrwxr-x  15 username  username   4096 Dec  1 15:01  hardware
drwxrwxr-x 361 username  username  12288 Dec  1 15:01  external
drwxrwxr-x  11 username  username   4096 Dec  1 14:47  device
drwxrwxr-x  21 username  username   4096 Dec  1 14:46  development
drwxrwxr-x   5 username  username   4096 Dec  1 14:45  developers
drwxrwxr-x   8 username  username   4096 Dec  1 14:45  dalvik
drwxrwxr-x  14 username  username   4096 Dec  1 14:44  cts
drwxrwxr-x  15 username  username   4096 Dec  1 14:41  bionic
-rw-rw-r--   1 username  username   2168 Dec  1 13:00  task
lrwxrwxrwx   1 username  username     19 Dec  1 09:32  Android.bp -> build/soong/root.bp
lrwxrwxrwx   1 username  username     26 Dec  1 09:32  bootstrap.bash -> build/soong/bootstrap.bash
drwxrwxr-x   8 username  username   4096 Dec  1 09:32  build
lrwxrwxrwx   1 username  username     23 Dec  1 09:32  BUILD -> build/bazel/bazel.BUILD
lrwxrwxrwx   1 username  username     27 Dec  1 09:32  WORKSPACE -> build/bazel/bazel.WORKSPACE
drwxrwxr-x   4 username  username   4096 Dec  1 09:32  bootable
drwxrwxr-x   7 username  username   4096 Dec  1 09:31  .repo
drwxr-xr-x   4 username  username   4096 Dec  1 05:24  Desktop
drwxr-xr-x   7 username  username   4096 Dec  1 04:53  Downloads
-rw-------   1 username  username  29235 Dec  1 00:20  .bash_history
drwxrwxr-x   6 username  username   4096 Nov 30 22:25  .android
drwxr-xr-x   6 username  username  24576 Nov 30 18:10  Pictures
drwxrwxr-x   5 username  username   4096 Nov 30 00:55  AndroidStudioProjects
drwx------   3 username  username   4096 Nov 29 15:03  .gnupg
drwxr-xr-x   2 username  username   4096 Nov 29 12:13  Documents
drwxrwxr-x  38 username  username   4096 Nov 29 07:13  art
-rw-rw-r--   1 username  username    115 Nov 28 21:59  .repo_.gitconfig.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 username  username     67 Nov 28 21:59  .gitconfig
drwxrwxr-x   3 username  username   4096 Nov 28 21:56  .repoconfig
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 28 04:52  ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 username  username   4096 Nov 23 01:18  Videos
-rw-rw-r--   1 username  username   3951 Nov 12 04:41 'Untitled Document 1'
drwxrwxr-x  10 username  username   4096 Nov  8 13:04  .gradle
drwx------  29 username  username   4096 Nov  8 12:57  .cache
drwxrwxr-x   3 username  username   4096 Nov  8 12:56  ApkProjects
drwxrwxr-x   3 username  username   4096 Nov  8 12:31  Android
drwxrwxr-x   3 username  username   4096 Nov  8 09:31  .masterpdfeditor
-rw-rw-r--   1 username  username   5013 Nov  4 19:47  english-notes
drwx------   7 username  username   4096 Nov  1 17:07  .zoom
drwxrwxr-x   4 username  username   4096 Sep 25 10:53  .java
drwxrwxr-x  13 username  username   4096 Sep 19 15:00  Android-SDK
drwx------   4 username  username   4096 Aug 22 03:26  snap
drwxrwxr-x   3 username  username   4096 Aug 17 04:28  .virtualenvs
-rw-r--r--   1 username  username   3857 Aug 17 04:28  .bashrc
drwx------   2 username  username   4096 Jul 19 21:41  .ssh
-rw-------   1 username  username     16 Jul 19 10:53  .emulator_console_auth_token
-rw-r--r--   1 username  username      0 Jul 17 18:59  .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwx------   6 username  username   4096 Jul 17 18:56  .thunderbird
drwx------   3 username  username   4096 Jul 17 18:49  .pki
drwx------   5 username  username   4096 Jul 17 18:33  .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x   2 username  username   4096 Jul 17 18:30  Music
drwxr-xr-x   2 username  username   4096 Jul 17 18:30  Public
drwxr-xr-x   2 username  username   4096 Jul 17 18:30  Templates
drwx------   3 username  username   4096 Jul 17 18:29  .local
-rw-r--r--   1 username  username    220 Jul 17 18:18  .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--   1 username  username    807 Jul 17 18:18  .profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-download to another directory and compare to your home directory.

Checking 60 objects can be done by hand. E.g. if `foo` is in the other directory then most likely `foo` in your home directory is from the download. If `bar` is in your home directory but not in the other directory then most likely it's not related to the download.

It may be some subdirectory was already there in your home directory with some files and the mishap added files to it; so maybe you need to compare directory trees. Comparing directory trees by hand is not a convenient way, so a better solution is needed in such case.

Still you should try this simple approach because *maybe* you'll find out only few files in your home directory are from the mishap and *maybe* you will be able to tell there are no "shared" directories. E.g. if your GUI file manager tells you in the properties of `baz/` in your home directory that there are as many files, directories, and the size is the same as for `baz/` in the other directory, then most likely `baz/` in your home directory is entirely from the download. Note sizes for identical file trees may differ if in different filesystems, even sometimes in the same filesystem ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1401094/432690)).

Some heuristics is required, but checking against a fresh download is the first thing I would consider.